# Why do they keep saying 217 is what's needed to elect the Speaker of the House?

Tags: united-states, house-of-representatives

There are 435 members of the U.S. House of Representatives.  The smallest absolute majority, if all members are present is 218, not 217.

Are there 2 seats that are empty (with an election planned)?  Which 2 districts?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[Two seats are vacant](https://www.cookpolitical.com/analysis/house/house-charts/house-open-seat-tracker) at this time.

> Current House Makeup Vacancies:

> RI-01: Rep. David Cicilline (D) resigned 6/1/23. Special primary 9/5/23, special general 11/7/23.

> UT-02: Rep. Chris Stewart (R) to resign 9/15/23. Special primary 9/5/23, special general 11/21/23.

Comment: It looks like one of the first orders of business for the House now that it has a Speaker may be to [expel yet another Republican](https://themessenger.com/politics/new-york-republicans-seek-to-expel-george-santos-from-the-house), making the math even closer. He's not in a sure-fire Republican district either. It was actually a Biden+10 district.

Comment: Following up on this comment, it in fact took about 5 weeks for Congress to get around to expelling Santos (not exactly "first order of business", but pretty damn speedy by their standards). Then, as warned, [Republicans lost the seat](https://www.cnn.com/politics/live-news/ny-special-election-santos-02-13-24/index.html), making their very narrow math even narrower.